# Why is there a memory leak when rendering pages to pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, promise, pdf.js

I use a pdf.js for rendering pages that are stored on the server, receiving data from each page. But if use the cycle to load 180 pages Ajax requests, it burns 500 MB of memory. In particular, they occupy rendered pages with mathematical formulas and graphs. A ready Pre-built version always eats about 100-200MB. Why so can be?

Here is the page render method. The file is taken and a single page is rendered, as each file is divided into Pdf files.

```
PDFJS.getDocument({
    data: atob(pageData)
}).then(function(pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('page-' + pageNum);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var viewport = page.getViewport(settings.scale);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var canvasP = document.getElementById('preview-page-' + pageNum);
        var contextP = canvasP.getContext('2d');
        var viewportP = page.getViewport(settings.previewScale);
        canvasP.height = viewportP.height;
        canvasP.width = viewportP.width;

        page.render({
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        }).then(function() {
            pdf.cleanup();
            pdf.destroy();
            page.cleanup();
            render.pagesStatus[pageNum] = pageRenderStatus.S;
        });
    });
}, function (reason) {
    render.pagesStatus[pageNum] = pageRenderStatus.E;
    console.error(reason);
});
```

Comment: Chrome's V8 doesn't immediately trigger garbage collection. It usually waits until it starts to reach the max heap limits before it does so. I'm not saying that PDF.js doesn't have a problem, but you should also know that without profiling it it's hard to know if this is really an issue or not.

Comment: An unrelated note: you wrote `render.pagesStatus[pageNum] == pageRenderStatus.E;` but you most likely want to do an assignment and not a comparison.

Comment: t.niese, yeah, I was sealed here, but it doesn't affect the memory leak.

Comment: Did you find out why it is leaking? Does it come from the pdfjs library?

Comment: I implemented what I wanted without this library. Does it come from the pdfjs library? Maybe Yes. I sent them issue.